# I want to use my raw input use my functions

Tags: python, function, raw-input

I have a program that i've been working on to see if I can use a raw input with my functions

```
class object:
# this shows that x is on top of y
    def on(self,x,y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        x = 1
        y = 0

        if x > y:
            print True
        else:
            print False
# this clears x making nothing be on top of x   
    def clear(self,x):
        self.x = x
        x = None
        print(x)
#  this shows that x is bigger than y 
    def heavy(self,x,y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        x = 1
        y = 0

        if x > y:
            print True
        else:
            print False

    input = raw_input("Enter an object: (Type stop to stop the loop): ") # raw input allows me to write string without the quotes
    obj = "" 
    while input != ("stop"):
        obj = obj + " " + input
        input = raw_input("Enter an object: ")
    print ("These are the objects: " + obj)
# this is a loop that allows the user to enter as many objects until they type stop
```

What i would like to happen is when the user enters a word of two, I can use the functions that i created. for example If i use on() (first function) it will display (on(word1,word2) and if i use clear it will display (clear(word1) clearing the second word. I just wanted to know if i am on the right track. Hope that is well explained thanks 
hope to be apart of this great community :)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It's not clear what kind of help you're asking for here/what the problem is. You may find it useful to read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922) and learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you are asking take a look at what I have below.

Below I have 4 defined variables. 3 of them will perform a different task. The 4th one is used to figure out what variable to use. I hope this points you in the right direction.

```
def random_words(word,word2):
    print (word +"\n"+"First"+"\n"+ word2)

# you can decide how to print each string given. 
# This will allow you to place one on top of the other. 
# the "\n" will print the following string on the next line.

def other_words(word,word2):
    print (word +" Second "+ word2)

def more_words(word,word2):
    print (word +" Third "+ word2)

def select_def(sdef,word,word2): # This variable will decide the others
    if sdef == "1":
        random_words(word,word2)
    elif sdef == "2":
        other_words(word,word2)
    else:
        more_words(word,word2)

var1= str(input("Enter a number -->"))
var2= str(input("Enter a Word -->"))
var3= str(input("Enter another -->"))

select_def(var1,var2,var3)
```

Example to call the function.

```
select_def("2","Makin","Bacon") #You can use something like this in an input function.
```

result:

```
>>> 
Makin Second Bacon
```

2nd example:

```
select_def("1","Makin","Bacon")
```

result:

```
>>> 
Makin
First
Bacon
```

Comment: This doesn't look particularly DRY. As a first-pass improvement, you could pass "first", "second" etc. To a single function.

Comment: I was just showing how you could select different functions using inputs of different strings. Its just a starting point. Proof of concept. They are trying to use input from the user to select the functions they have made.

Comment: Fair enough, I'm on my phone so can't elaborate too much, but it seems they already have methods that violate DRY and asked if it was the right approach?

Comment: You are probably correct. I have only been learning python and programing for about 2 1/2 months now. I am sure there are cleaner ways of producing the results they are looking for.